A data extract by multiple conditions in Google Sheet is working for one raw, but I can't "arrayformula it"
I'm trying to create a table on a sheet, filled with data from multiple tables stacked in another sheet.
A simplified file is here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uh3QjnDXmn3eyFtaGkJxWCyjwcNm3NdNQI3H-W0rZMo/edit?usp=share_link
The source sheet, "Training", contains all my training sessions.
Training Sheet
I use this file since ever, it's a five thousands raws sheet, so it's hard to reorganize its logic.
Here is how it works. For each session, I paste a "mini-table" on top of the last one.
On the first raw of each table, there is the session date column B, and the type of training column E. There can be more than one session a day, and when it's the case, each table shows the same date.
I'd like to be able to analyse some evolutions now, see graphs, and so on, so I'm gonna need to extract data to fill a more classical tables.
The first one I want to create is the sheet "Running".
Running Sheet
I added an arrayformula on A2 so column A automatically adds all dates of the tables where column E is " - Jogging"
I named some ranges, but I can change that if you think it creates problems :

Training! B:B is SessionDate

Training! E:E is SessionType

Running! A:A is TableDate


Now, I'd like to put a  formula on B2 so column B is automatically filled with the duration of each date session. So, it needs to do two things (at least) and I don't find the way to organize the formula without getting errors (value 1 not found, when I use match with multiple criteria ; impossibility to develop, requiring to add more lines (but I have plenty empty)...) ;

Find every tables in Training where the date in B matchs the one on Running A, AND where E is " - Jogging"

Then, find the duration which is on column F AND one raw lower


I don't know if it's super easy or if I created a nightmare. Thanks in advance for any help.
I tried various combination of MATCH, FILTER, ARRAYFORMULA, and INDEX. I'm not good at all with spreadsheets so I tried to work with ChatGPT. Nothing worked.

Can you manually add & showcase your ideal expected numbers in the test sheet?!

Based from your Running tab, have you tried using the Query function instead?

@rockinfreakshow, sure, I just did. I only asked for help regarding column B, assuming that I'd replicate the solution for the others, but I just filled everything in case the solution embrace the full table.

@PatrickdC, I used it once, long time ago. I guess it could work. I'm gonna dig into this right now. I'll let you know.


You may try:
=filter(hstack(Training!B:B,vstack(choosecols(Training!F2:N,1,3,5,7,8),)),Training!E:E=" - Jogging")



It works! I worked on it until 5am, landed on a three lines query with curly bracket arrays...that didn't work. I'm gonna study your right now. Thanks @rockinfreakshow.
